# Pandas - Speed Up Calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, 'data' as follows:

```
data.head(3)
     Time          Value
0    01:00:00.125  5
1    01:02:03.145  3
2    01:02:03.651  9
```

I am trying to create a new column that provides, on each row, the highest 'Value' for the existing row and all rows before that row that occured 5 seconds or less before the current row's timestamp. My current method is an incredibly slow for loop, and I am wondering if there is a faster way?

For reference, my current code loops through all the rows, gets the current time, calculates the time that was 5 seconds before the current time, creates a new frame with only the rows that fall in that interval, and then takes the maximum of 'Value' column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the rolling functionality in pandas:

```
col = data.rolling(window='5s', on='Time').max()
data['aggregate'] = col['Value']
```

Comment: Did not know .rolling() supports using time periods.

Comment: Hit the following error: NotImplementedError: ops for Rolling for this dtype timedelta64[ns] are not implemented

Comment: Works fine for me, even with timedelta. What version of pandas are you using? Looks like this functionality has been added in version 0.19: 
 http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#rolling-is-now-time-series-aware

Comment: I am using 0.20.1...I will try the earlier version.

Comment: The issue had to do with having a series outside of my frame that was used to create the time column. When I created the time column using only columns within the frame it worked.